# frida-example-agent npm run build not correct

Tags: javascript, frida

I git clone frida-example-agent and run `npm install` and `npm run build`, but the output is wired, like below

```
928 /agent/index.js.map
578 /agent/index.js
215 /agent/logger.js.map
58 /agent/logger.js
✄
```

I don't know ts module or frida-compile's source much, I tried to change different frida-compile version or CompilerOptions but not working...
And it makes me crazy that once a time when I change different python env with conda, It works!!, it is very strange. But after I reclone from github it get wroing again and I didn't change any file of it...
If you have met the same problem, thanks a lot to share your solution or advice to me)_)

Comment: When something sometimes works and then not you should check the environment and the command output on stdout/sdterr. So I would note the available node.js version(s) and the command output every time you execute `npm install` also check the installed node packages frida-example-agent depends on.

Comment: I tried different node version,  v14.15.0, v16.20.2,.v18.17.1, not work at all, and the repo only rely on frida-compile15.0.8 and frida-compile itself seems working fine

Comment: I found the same problem in [frida-compile' issue](https://github.com/frida/frida-compile/issues/60), but it's not closed, I just want a local env that can work fine. What should I do?